# how to delete duplicate content and copy the value in the last column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Please have a look at the format belwow , i want to delete the duplicate rows and copy the last column content to its original row.

In the below picture, i want to delete duplicate contents row A4 and copy the content of C4 life to C3 so that C3 becomes - god,life . To delete the row, the content of A and B should be the same. 
In third row, A3,B3 ,A4,B4 are same so we can delete it.

In seventh and Eight row ,A7 and A8 are the same but B7 and B8 are different , so it shouldn't be deleted.

But in Eight row , A8,A9  and B8,B9 are also the same so ninth Row A9 should be deleted and C8 becomes Marriage,Beauty

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought much about how you will setup your logic? I would start with A1 and compare it to the remaining A rows until you reach a blank one. If you find a cell that matches the one under test start looking at the B,C cells to compare the text. If it matches combine the C cells then delete that row. Then step to the next A cell and do the process again. I haven't tested this code but it should get you started.

```
 Dim OuterIndex As Integer
 Dim InnerIndex As Integer

    Do While Cells(OuterIndex, 0).Value <> "" ' Loop through all the cells in Column A and stop when you find a blank one

        InnerIndex = 0 ' Reset this each time through the loop

       Do While Cells(InnerIndex, 0).Value <> "" ' Compare one cell to all the remaining, stop when you get to a blank and increment the search for the next row.

            If Cells(OuterIndex, 0).Value = Cells(InnerIndex, 0).Value Then ' This is when you find a match for the A cells

                ' Now compare the B cell for these two cells. If The B cells don't match then exit

                If Cells(OuterIndex, 1).Value = Cells(InnerIndex, 1).Value Then
                    ' Here we found a matching A and B cell so compbine the contents of the C cells in the test row and delete the second one
                    Cells(OuterIndex, 2).Value = Cells(OuterIndex, 2).Value & "," & Cells(InnerIndex, 2).Value
                    Rows(InnerIndex).Delete
                    ' We don't want to increment the InnerIndex since we need to reevaluate the same row again now that we deleted it and the rows shifted up
                    Else
                    ' B cells were different so increment to the next row
                    InnerIndex = InnerIndex + 1

                End If

            Else
            ' A cells were different so increment to the next row
            InnerIndex = InnerIndex + 1
            End If


      Loop

        OuterIndex = OuterIndex + 1 ' Increment to the next index

  Loop
```